# how to not marshall boolean attributes with default values while converting object to JSON Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_DEFAULT)` does not marshall any attribute with default value, but in this scenario I need int attributes with default values as well in the JSON response.

One way I am thinking, is writing a custom serializer to not marshall only boolean attributes with default values. Is there any other approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
```

Making the above configuration would exclude fields with default values even if you explicitly set them as there is no way to check if a value is assigned by default or is explicitly assigned.

As in your case you need to only exclude boolean fields with default values , your best way would be to use Boolean class instead of boolean primitive and keep null serialization off so that it is not marshalled.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However the response is data driven from downstream services. Values are set in the objects irrespective of false. It would be additional computation to not set values if they are false. Is there any other approach.